# Plot geom_col with % change trend line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot an image similar to this on ggplot [image]

How can I do this? I am facing troubles setting the axis to only show one value. This is what I have tried so far.

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Values  Year  change
   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1  12307  1999   NA   
2   6267  2000  -96.4 
3   6119  2001   -2.42
4   9254  2002   33.9 
5   3124  2003 -196.   

ggplot(df) +
  geom_col(aes(x= Year, y = Values)) +
  geom_line(aes(x= Year, y = change))
```

Comment: Which values do you want to plot as bars and which value as points?

Comment: Values as bars and percentage changes as points on the line

Comment: But the `changes` are negative, whereas `Values` are positive so the points would not be on the bar as shown in your image.

Comment: Ronak Shah makes a good point, this visualization  does not represent the data properly, the Y scales for the changes are not systematic, which makes it very hard for the information to be digested

Comment: Could it be possible to not represent the bar values on the axis, but with labels like in the image? Then the y-axis could be purely for the % change values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be your best choice, since the visualization you want is not fundamentally sound. which will help your viewer be able to see the relationship, but you could also look into other visualizations that help show the relationship between these 3 variables

```
   readin <- "  Values  Year  change
1  12307  1999   0   
2   6267  2000  -96.4 
3   6119  2001   -2.42
4   9254  2002   33.9 
5   3124  2003 -196.0  "

df <- read.table(text = readin, header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

p1 <- ggplot(df) + aes(x= Year, y = Values, label = Values) +    geom_col() + geom_text(vjust = -0.5)

p2 <- ggplot(df) + aes(x= Year, y = change, label = change) +    geom_line() + geom_text(vjust = -0.5)


grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow=1, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes thank you. I know you are a great R user, I want to be able to help like you Ronak. Thank you for the code advice

Comment: Is there anyway to overlay these layers but only show one of the axis?

Answer (score 3):

I completely agree with all the concerns raised here involving the interpretability of the plot with the secondary y-axis. IMO secondary axes should *always* be avoided.

That said, `ggplot` allows you to use a secondary y-axis; all that needs to be done is to scale data on the secondary axis (here: `change`) and use the reverse transformation inside `sec.axis`. The transformation is given by a simple linear model: `y_scaled = a0 + a1 * y_original`.

Here's an attempt to reproduce the plot:

```r
a1 <- (0 - max(df$Values, na.rm = TRUE) / (diff(-range(df$change, na.rm = TRUE))))
a0 <- max(df$Values, na.rm = TRUE) - a1 * max(df$change, na.rm = TRUE)


library(hrbrthemes)   # For dark ggplot theme
library(tidyverse)    # For ggplot and dplyr
df %>%
    mutate(change_scaled = a0 + a1 * change) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Year, Values)) +
    geom_col(fill = "#00D987", colour = NA) +
    geom_text(
        aes(y = Values, label = Values),
        colour = "#00D987",
        vjust = -1) +
    scale_y_continuous(
        limits = c(0, 1.1 * max(df$Values)),
        sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a0) / a1,name = "Change")) +
    geom_point(
        aes(x = Year, y = change_scaled, group = 1), colour = "#FE9E00") +
    geom_line(
        aes(x = Year, y = change_scaled, group = 1), colour = "#FE9E00") +
    theme_ft_rc() +
    theme(
        axis.title.y = element_text(color = "#00D987"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "#FE9E00"))
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```r
df <- read.table(text = " Values  Year  change
12307  1999   NA
 6267  2000  -96.4
 6119  2001   -2.42
 9254  2002   33.9
 3124  2003 -196.
", header = T)
```

Comment: this is great, you did the right thing and didn't use the NA, when I used 0.

Comment: @DanielJachetta Personally, I'd go with your solution; much cleaner and no axes abuse. I have seen very very few graphs where a secondary axis actually "works".

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. I agree with the points about secondary axis and that's why I wanted to just represent one of the axes with labels on the chart, but your solution is great too

Comment: @zhao It's not about showing only one axis vs. showing two axes. It's about what data to show in one plot. The need for a secondary axis only arises because you are trying to plot `Values` *and* `change` in the same plot. It's much better to make two separate plots (e.g. using facets or with `grid.arrange`).